# replacing string based on user input c++

Tags: c++, string, file, replace

i want to receive an input from user and search a file for that input. when i found a line that includes that specific word, i want to print it and get another input to change a part of that line based on second user input with third user input. (I'm writing a hospital management app and this is a part of project that patients and edit their document).
i completed 90 percent of the project but i don't know how to replace it. check out following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stream>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std; 

int main(){
    string srch;
    string line;
    fstream Myfile;
    string word, replacement, name;
    int counter;
    Myfile.open("Patientlist.txt", ios::in|ios::out);
    cout << "\nEnter your Name: ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, srch);

    if(Myfile.is_open())
    {
        while(getline(Myfile, line)){
            if (line.find(srch) != string::npos){
                cout << "\nYour details are: \n" << line << endl << "What do you want to change? *type it's word and then type the replacement!*" << endl;
                cin >> word >> replacement;
            } 
            // i want to change in here
        }
    }else
    {
        cout << "\nSearch Failed...  Patient not found!" << endl;
    }  
    Myfile.close();
    
    }
```

for example  my file contains this line ( David , ha , 2002 ) and user wants to change 2002 to 2003

Comment: You cannot replace the string directly in the file. You have to write what you read in a second file, then rename/delete the original one, then rename the output file to the original name.

Comment: @zdf can you show me in code how can i do this? I don't have much experience working with c++ thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot replace the string **directly in the file**. You have to:

1. **Write to a temporary** file what you read & changed.
2. **Rename the original** one (or delete it if you are sure everything went fine).
3. **Rename the temporary** file to the original one.

Ideally, the rename part should be done in **one step**. For instance, you do not want to end up with no file because the original file was deleted but the temporary one was not renamed due to some error - see your OS documentation for this.

Here's an idea:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

void replace(string& s, const string& old_str, const string& new_str)
{
  for (size_t off = 0, found_idx = s.find(old_str, off); found_idx != string::npos; off += new_str.length(), found_idx = s.find(old_str, off))
    s.replace(found_idx, old_str.length(), new_str);
}

int main()
{
  const char* in_fn = "c:/temp/in.txt";
  const char* bak_fn = "c:/temp/in.bak";
  const char* tmp_fn = "c:/temp/tmp.txt";
  const char* out_fn = "c:/temp/out.txt";

  string old_str{ "2002" };
  string new_str{ "2003" };

  // read, rename, write
  {
    ifstream in{ in_fn };
    if (!in)
      return -1; // could not open

    ofstream tmp{ tmp_fn };
    if (!tmp)
      return -2; // could not open

    string line;
    while (getline(in, line))
    {
      replace(line, old_str, new_str);
      tmp << line << endl;
    }
  } // in & tmp are closed here

  // this should be done in one step 
  {
    remove(bak_fn);
    rename(in_fn, bak_fn);

    remove(out_fn);
    rename(tmp_fn, in_fn);

    remove(tmp_fn);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- The header is supposed to be `<fstream>` rather than `<stream>`
- you can't read and write to a file simultaneously so I have closed the file after reading before reopening the file for writing.
- **instead of updating text inside the file, your `line` can be updated and then written to file.**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std; 

int main(){
    string srch;
    string line, line2;
    fstream Myfile;
    string word, replacement, name;
    int counter;
    Myfile.open("Patientlist.txt", ios::in);
    cout << "\nEnter your Name: ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, srch);

    if(Myfile.is_open())
    {
        while(getline(Myfile, line)){
            if (line.find(srch) != string::npos){
                cout << "\nYour details are: \n" << line << endl << "What do you want to change? *type it's word and then type the replacement!*" << endl;
                cin >> word >> replacement;

                int index = line.find(word);

                if (index != string::npos){
                    Myfile.close();

                    Myfile.open("Patientlist.txt", ios::out);

                    line.replace(index, word.length(), replacement);
                    Myfile.write(line.data(), line.size());

                    Myfile.close();
                }
            } 
            // i want to change in here
        }
    }else
    {
        cout << "\nSearch Failed...  Patient not found!" << endl;
    }  
    
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible way:
Close the file after you read it into "line" variable, then:

`std::replace(0, line.length(), "2002", "2003")`

Then overwrite the old file.
**Note that std::replace is different from string::replace!!**